# Car wants to die in low RPM when I start it and jerks when stopped if it hasn't warmed up

Tags: chrysler, stall, sebring

I have a 95 chrysler sebring lxi. The car started jerkin when I stopped at lights if it wasn't running for a while and it would slip out of gear on the freeway, I put some Lucas stop leak into the transmission and it was better for a while and it no longer slips on freeway but now when I start it if I don't warm the car up in neutral before driving it sometimes it dies if I stop, and it jerks as well when trying to stop. I recently did all my fluids so I'm not sure what this could be. I can't afford a mechanic, hoping there's something I can look at or try myself.

Answer (score 1):

Jerking while stopping can be caused by the Idle Air Control Valve. It may need cleaning, or it may need replacing. They can be had for cheap at the junkyard, swap it just to see if it helps. If it does, you can look at your old one and see if a cleaning will help, or replacement by a brand new one, or run the junkyard one.